# File handling to import text into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, text

Recently i created in php simple script to import words from a text file and randomly pick one of them. To achieve it i created such class:

```
class RandomizeWords {

    public static function display() {
        $contents = file_get_contents("../dictionary.txt");
        $lines = explode("\n", $contents);
        $randomWords = ucfirst($lines[array_rand($lines)]);
        return $randomWords;
    }

}
```

Now, for fun, i wanted to make it work using javascript instead of php but i'm missing something or javascript can't work on files without using technologies like ajax, jquery or node.js which, imo, are overkill for such simple task. Am i wrong or am i forced to use node.js or something similar?

Comment: Use Ajax, it can't be overkill because it's native JavaScript. While jQuery or Node.JS may be overkill, Ajax certainly isn't. That said jQuery can certainly make using Ajax easier and work better across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that PHP is a server side scripting language that is made for managing, working with, serving, reading and writing files, while javascript is a client side scripting language, that is restricted from system access for security reasons. The way the two languages communicate between two different systems is through AJAX requests, or just plain GET,POST,PUT & DELETE requests. You can try and use a FileReader() javascript class, if the file is local to the script, but it does not look like the function has cross browser support. Here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Otherwise you need to start learning Asynchronous programming and node.js.

Comment: I keep on digging and found info about something called fetch api. Seems like something fitting my needs. After quick reading i've tried to write some code using it but seems to be not working or i just made a mistake somewhere as i'm not so good with js overall. Here is the code i made:
var text = document.querySelector('p');

fetch('../dictionary.txt').then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(myBlob) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  text.src = objectURL;
});

Comment: You are probably better off learning jQuery the fetch api uses promises which means it is asynchronous programming, promises make it easier to deal with but you still have to understand asychronous programming patterns, which means you can't code them and expect top to bottom execution like regular javascript. You notice the then.() pattern that chains together function calls, that means the code is executing asynchronously, You can make a simple AJAX request pretty easily, you just have to make sure that dependent code does not execute until the Ajax requests have been fulfilled.